# Redundant code, how can I have multiple arguments per line

Tags: powershell

This script works, I want to condense it so if I add more lines to find and replace in the file I'm not being redundant.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\JonSa\Desktop -Filter callcounts.xml | Foreach-         Object{
(Get-Content $_.FullName) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "@aXXXXX.ac1.vbspbx.com", ""} | 
Set-Content $_.FullName
}
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\JonSa\Desktop -Filter callcounts.xml | Foreach-   Object{
(Get-Content $_.FullName) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "sip:", ""} | 
Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

I would like to accomplish this with fewer lines that leaves room for more arguments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, this code is working as stated in the question it would be better suited for codereview.stackechange

Comment: So the question is about making all replaces in one go?

Comment: Yes, I feel it is inefficient doing it this way if I need to add another 20 replacements, or is this the preferred solution?

Comment: You could make a function that takes a regex array as a parameter. You do have to be careful of just string replacements in that fashion, though. For example, if you replace `@axxx` and then want to replace `@axxx.something.com`, your second regex will match nothing since `@axxx` will have already been replaced. You will need to have a good understanding of your data formats and strategically place the proper anchors, quantifiers, and meta characters throughout the regexes. It is completely doable but not as thoughtless code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- With only one file, don't use `Get-ChildItem` and a `ForEach-Object`
- when using the `-raw` -parameter, you can apply the replace on the whole file
- you can also append several `-replace` one after the other.
- for the same replacement (here none) you can use an alternation `|` (OR)
- an empty replacement can be omitted with the `-replace` operator (not so with the `.replace()` method)

---

```
$File = 'C:\Users\JonSa\Desktop\callcounts.xml'
(Get-Content $File -raw) -replace '@aXXXXX.ac1.vbspbx.com|sip:' | 
 Set-Content $File
```